# How to get the displayed range in Kaminari

Tags: ruby-on-rails, kaminari

I need to customize `_pagination.html.erb` to display the same information as the `page_entries_info` helper method, for example: *Showing records 6 to 10 of 26.*

Having a `_pagination.html.erb` like this:

```
<%= paginator.render do -%>

<% end -%>
```

What methods or objects are available to get the currently displayed range (6 to 10 in the example above), and the total number of records being paginated (26, in the example)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First approach, you could override Kaminari localize to display format `"Showing %{entry_name} %{first} to %{last} of %{total}"`

```rb
# config/locales/kaminari.yml
en:
 ...
 
   helpers:
    page_entries_info:
      entry:
        zero: "entries"
        one: "entry"
        other: "entries"
      one_page:
        display_entries:
          zero: "No %{entry_name} found"
          one: "Showing <b>1</b> %{entry_name}"
          other: "Showing <b>all %{count}</b> %{entry_name}"
      more_pages:
        display_entries: "Showing %{entry_name} %{first} to %{last} of %{total}"
```

Second approach, as you want to custom `_pagination.html.erb`

```rb
# app/views/kaminari/_pagination.html.erb
<%= paginator.render do -%>
  <% to = current_page.to_i * per_page %>
  <% from = to - per_page + 1 %>
  <% total = total_pages * per_page - 1 %>
  Showing <%= @options[:entry_name].pluralize(total, I18n.locale) %> <%= from %> to <%= to %> of <%= total %>
 
...

<% end %>

# you need to pass an option `entry_name`
# app/views/records/index.html.erb
<%= paginate @records, entry_name: 'record' %>
```

Comment: Thank you. For the second approach, is there a way to get the total number of records? That would help in the edge cases where there is only one page with less than per_page records, and when the total number of records is less than total_pages * per_page.

Comment: @Victor pass `@records.length` as option `total`: `paginate @records, entry_name: 'record', total: @records.length`, then you could show total as `@options[:total]`